# Need background image stretch to cover the whole canvas in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

i can upload the background image. but i don't kmow how strech to cover the whole canvas. 
sample code

```
var fr = new FileReader;
fr.onload = function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        var imgwidth = this.width;
        currentcanvas.setBackgroundImage(fr.result, currentcanvas.renderAll.bind(currentcanvas), {

          scaleX: currentcanvas.width / imgwidth,
            scaleY: currentcanvas.height / imgwidth
        });
        currentcanvas.renderAll();
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

In fabricjs 2.x, things are very different. Here's the code to stretch a background image to canvas size for fabricjs 2.x:

```
// Assume fcanvas is fabricjs canvas:
fabric.Image.fromURL('background.png', function(img){
   img.scaleToWidth(fcanvas.width);
   img.scaleToHeight(fcanvas.height);
   fcanvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
   fcanvas.requestRenderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give background image's height and width according to canvas height and width as follow :

```
canvas.backgroundImage.width = canvas.getWidth();
canvas.backgroundImage.height = canvas.getHeight();
```

Comment: Not working for me. backgroundImage does not exist, and backgroundColor (the other way for setting an image as backgrund) does not have such function

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width props to the height and width of the canvas.

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(imgObj, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
   width: canvas.width,
   height: canvas.height,
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps!

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(url, function() {
  let img = canvas.backgroundImage;
  img.originX = 'left';
  img.originY = 'top';
  img.scaleX = canvas.getWidth() / img.width;
  img.scaleY = canvas.getHeight() / img.height;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```